# Android | Change overflow icon(3 dot menu) color?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, themes

I have searched a solution for this and I tried multiple solutions but none of them worked for me.

**Here is my style.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>


    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

How can I change the 3 dot menu icon color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Add a new drawable of three dot menu of the color you want in the project.**

**2. Create a new style**

```
<style name="OverFlow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/overflow</item>
</style>
```

**3. Apply that style to your main style theme**
`<item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>`

Comment: But for that I would have to generate icon for each screen density size. I don't know how to do that